# Add content to My Watch app menu

Tags: ios, watch

How can I add content to the app in My Watch app menu?

Like Stocks:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I don't know how! I want to know where I have to write the code to do the same that STOCKS app (default Apple app)

Comment: ok, see this link: http://blog.patrickbalestra.com/post/110726459321/watchkit-settings-bundle